# How to manage strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I have been wondering about how people manage their strings if they are likely to change?

Like... Do you hardcode, use a property list or strings file? Any other methods?

Comment: This question is too broad, and not a good fit according to the FAQ (sounds like you want to have a discussion, not have something explained).

Comment: I agree with borrrden... You need to be specific of your inquiries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually depends on the type of strings, I'll give some examples:

1. UI strings -> Put them into Localizable.strings and use `NSLocalizedString` macro.
2. Server URL -> hardcode (meaning to put them into a separate header) or specify them as build parameter.
3. Parsing strings  (e.g. keys for JSON dictionaries) -> hardcode
4. App is based on text strings (e.g. Dictionary App) -> Database

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But isn't Localizable.strings only for localications? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can have only one localization and it's always good to have your app i18n ready.

Answer (score 0):

If they are to be used in the classes such as for notifications and/or for dictionary keys
you would define them

```
 #define MYOWN_NOTIFICATION @"NotifySth"
    #define CITY_KEY @"city"
```

If you are going to have a small collection of strings then a plist would be the way to go
You will then use it to load it inside an NSDictionary or NSArray

If you have a large collection of strings then store them in a db and query the string basing on your own criteria